# How to replace a variable's value after a mysqli query and the results are bound?

Tags: php, mysqli

for some reason i cannot get this to work, but basically i am trying to change what is stored in a variable after a mysqli query, but for whatever reason, it will not work, here is my code:

```
$q = $DBH->prepare("SELECT text, position FROM persons WHERE id = ?");
$q->bind_param("i", $id);
$q->execute();
$q->bind_result($text,$position);
if($position <= 5){
$text = "position is too low";
}
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.
You've bound results to variables, but never fetched them.
So, you just need to call $q->fetch() before using results.

Answer (score 0):

A mistype?

> $q->bind_result($text,**position**);

Comment: no, sorry, i retyped that out instead of copy and pasting, the query runs fine without any syntax errors, so i am confused as to why this is.